# iOS Dismiss previous ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

I'm presenting a new ViewController with the following code

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
finishViewController *finished = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"finishViewController"];
[self presentViewController:finished animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When finishViewController the previous view (the one with the above code on) is still processing in the background. Is there a way I can kill it?

Comment: What processing is happening? Can't you just add a method to stop the processing?

Comment: I could, but the view isn't needed anymore so there is no point in it being in the memory. I thought this would be fairly easy...

Comment: If the view isn't in memory, how is it doing things in the background?

Comment: What happening is the new view is displayed, then the viewController that you just came from is still processing behind it. I was to dismiss that view controller from memory.

Comment: Are you running into memory problems?

Comment: After several times of running the view yes. There is just no need for it to exist once the next view is pushed.

Comment: Sadly no...had to make do with a work around.